# Finding $S^c \cup T^c$ and $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k$. Help with understanding textbook answer.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Problem(1): Find $S^c \cup T^c$ if $S = (0, 1)$; $T = \left[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right]$

The textbook says that the answer is $(-\infty, \frac{1}{2}] \cup [1, \infty)$. I say the answer is $(-\infty, \frac{1}{2}) \cup [1, \infty)$.

Problem(2): Find $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k$ if $S_k = (1 - \frac{1}{k}, 2 + \frac{1}{k})$.

The textbook says the answer is $[0, 2]$. I say the answer is $[1, 2]$.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I feel pretty confident I'm right, so I'm clueless as to where I'd be messing up.

Comment: Looks like the textbook is wrong on these two counts.

Comment: Thanks @Mindlack! When I got the first question "wrong" I assumed that the book had a typo but I started to worry when I got the next question "wrong" too!